# Why this break can't get me out of this while-do loop?

Tags: shell, shell-script

code:

This is for creating some animation and when the count variable `$i` gets 5, it stops and carry on the future shell code.

```
chars="/-\|"

while :; do
  for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
    sleep 0.1
    echo -en "${chars:$i:1}" "\r"
    if [ $i == 5 ]
    then
        break
    fi
  done
done

# code below are never get executed.
```

Comment: `$i` never reaches `5`, it's maximum is `3`, which cause the `for` loop end because `${#chars}` is `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it breaks out of the closest loop, which is the `for`, not the `while`. Try `break 2` instead.

Comment: But more importantly, `$i` will never equal 5 because its range only goes up to 3 (`${#chars}`).

Comment: Thanks! What does the `2` in `break 2` mean?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Have a look at `help break`. `break N` breaks N levels of loops. `break` is equivalent to `break 1`.

Answer (score 2):

2 things can be added :

1. As the character variable max value is 3 (count starts from 0 ends with 3 - in total 4 characters). so it can break at 3 (for loop/inner loop breaks)
2. To stop for the outer loop/while loop , it needs a condition to break out. Here there is no need of while loop.

solution 1 : No use of while loop

```
chars="/-\|"
  for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
    sleep 0.1
    echo -en "${chars:$i:1}" "\r"
    if [ $i == 3 ]; then
        break;
    fi
 done
```

solution 2 : You can use exit to quit which will quit out of the script.

```
chars="/-\|"
while :; do
  for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
    sleep 0.1
    echo -en "${chars:$i:1}" "\r"
    if [ $i == 3 ]; then
        exit;
    fi
 done
done
```

Comment: exit will quit the whole script so the following part below will never get executed.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo, Thats intentional if you want to quit at some point  from the script itself.